# What is the difference between these two type of initialization in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to initialize the content of a list in a listfragment from onCreate() method of an Activity.

Part of Activity code:

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dish);
            FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();
                    mDishListFragment = new DishListFragment();
                transaction1.add(R.id.dishList_fragment, mDishListFragment, "DishListFragment");
                transaction1.commit();

mDishListFragment.showItem(totalList.get(0));
    }
```

Part of Fragment Code:

```
BinderData adapter = null;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> dishDataCollection;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("emenu", "Dishlistfragment on create");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new BinderData(getActivity(), R.id.article);
    }
public void showItem(List<HashMap<String, String>> map) {
        dishDataCollection = map;       
        if (dishDataCollection != null) {
            adapter.init(dishDataCollection); //NullPOinterException
        }   
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

I get a nullpointerException at when initialising my custom adapter.

Now, this code works perfectly fine when i initialize my fragment in a different way in the activity. Like this:

```
mDishListFragment = (DishListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.dishList_fragment);
```

instead of initializing the way I did in the **first** code bock above.

I need to use fragment transaction add() method because i need to be able to hide and show the fragment whenever needed.

What is the difference between the two type of initialisation and why is the former not working while the latter does?

Hope you guys can help. Please let me know if you need any other part of the code.

For your reference, the adapter code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView thumb_image;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> dishDataCollection;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public BinderData(Context context, int list_row) {
        // super(context , list_row , map);
        super(context, list_row);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void init(List<HashMap<String, String>> map) {
        this.dishDataCollection = map;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return idlist.size();
        return dishDataCollection.size();
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView != null)
            if (position == mItemIndex) {
                convertView.setSelected(true);
                convertView.setPressed(true);
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);
            } else {
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
            }

        View vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.dish); // city name
            holder.rate = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.rate); // city weather
                                                                    // overview
            holder.shortdescription = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.shortdescription); // city temperature
            holder.dishImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb
                                                                                // image
                                                                                // vi.setActivated(true);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        // Setting all values in listview

        holder.name.setText(dishDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_NAME));
        holder.rate.setText(dishDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_RATE));
        holder.shortdescription.setText(dishDataCollection.get(position).get(
                KEY_SHORT));

        // Setting an image
        String uri = "drawable/"
                + dishDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON);
        int imageResource = vi
                .getContext()
                .getApplicationContext()
                .getResources()
                .getIdentifier(
                        uri,
                        null,
                        vi.getContext().getApplicationContext()
                                .getPackageName());
        Drawable image = vi.getContext().getResources()
                .getDrawable(imageResource);
        holder.dishImage.setImageDrawable(image);

        return vi;
    }

    /*
     * 
     * */
    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView name;
        TextView rate;
        TextView shortdescription;
        ImageView dishImage;
    }

    public void setSelectItem(int index) {
        mItemIndex = index;
    }

    public int getSelectItem() {
        return mItemIndex;
    }
```

Comment: The difference is that in the first example you are creating a new instance of your DishListFragment and in the second example you are creating a pointer to an existing instance of the fragment.  You should focus on the NullPointerExceptions and figure out what is causing that.

Comment: Can you put the code of BinderData class?

Comment: @RaúlJuárez: I just added the adapter. Please not that I am getting the nullPointer error even when i replace the listview with a simple textView and i try to setText() on it. What i mean to say is, it seems to be a problem not with the adapter.

Comment: After you call `commit` in your transaction, call `executePendingTransactions` method on transaction1

Answer (score 0):

in fragment's `onCreate()` your view is not yet existing. YOu should move your initialization code to `onCreateView()`. Get familiar with fragments life cycle: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

You may have to inflate the View rather than setContentView(R.layout.activity_dish);

```
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rsslist_overview,
    container, false);
```

**Example**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail,
        container, false);
    return view;
  }

  public void setText(String item) {
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    view.setText(item);
  }
}
```